# Como fazer um círculo no CSS sem Border-Radius 100%?

Tags: html, css

Sei fazer um círculo no css com `border-radius`.

```css
.circle{
    border-radius:100%;
    border:10px solid red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Porém gostaria de saber se existe outra forma, além dessa, em CSS.

Comment: Tem como usar imagem, da uma olhada .http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/?redirect_from_locale=pt

Comment: Não, imagem não, por favor!

Comment: Retiro o que disse. Interessante @PauloHDSousa

Comment: `svg` é uma opção?

Comment: kkkk SIM. Mas sei que tem outra forma ;)

Comment: É simples, use border-radius 50% :P    - Brincadeiras à parte, 50% faz mais sentido, pois cada borda pega só 50% da horizontal e da vertical. Quando você põe 100%, o _browser_ tá "ajeitando" a medida na marra.

Comment: Eu iria responder isso @Bacco, mas refiz a leitura do post, e o titulo deveria ser "como fazer um círculo no CSS sem border-radius" :p

Comment: Após ler as respostas uma coisa posso notar, `border-radius` para a maior parte das necessidades sempre vai ser mais prático que qualquer outra coisa.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simples: usando `border-radius: 50%`, que seria mais correto. Cada quadrante atingido pelo `radius` só pega metade da largura/altura, não tem muito sentido 100%. É o que precisa pra grande maioria dos casos. Só não pode esquecer do `overflow-hidden` se tiver conteúdo que possa "escapar" nas quinas.

Mas para não deixar de responder, que tal apenas usando o *background* do CSS, com um degradê radial?

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,#f00 0%,#f00 0%,#f00 67%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%);
```

Veja em ação:

```css
#circulo1 {
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#f00 0%,#f00 98%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}

#circulo2 {
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side,
     #999 0%,#999 74%,#e00 76%,#e00 98%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}

#circulo3 {
  background:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,
     rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 78%,#fff 80%,#fff 94%,
     #36f 96%,#36f 99%,#fff 100%),
     url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVmIb.png) no-repeat center/160px 160px;
}

body {background-color:#fff}
div {width:160px;height:160px;float:left;margin:10px}
```

```html
<div id="circulo1"></div>
<div id="circulo2"></div>
<div id="circulo3"></div>
```

Notar que as duas primeiras tem transparência no entorno, mas terceira depende de se acertar o *gradient* com o fundo da página.

Comment: Muito interessante @Bacco.

Answer (score 14):

Se `SVG` for uma opção

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Eu sei que não tem `CSS` aí no meio, mas fica registrada uma opção. `SVG` tá bem em alta no momento, e [esse artigo do css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) mostra uma série de coisas que podem ser feitas com ele. Aliás, recomendo uma análise da logo desse site, que tem um easter egg bem bacana!

**EDIT**

A logo do site não tem mais o easter egg que eu comentei. =(

Comment: É tipo como se fosse uma imagem, só que ao mesmo tempo "só que não".

Comment: É por aí, @WallaceMaxters. `SVG` é poderosíssimo, vale a pena estudá-lo

Comment: Meu cérebro está tentando entender o -1 até agora ;)

Comment: La vida es dura, @WallaceMaxters =/

Answer (score 7):

Fora `border-radius` e `background` se o seu desejo for realmente usar nas imagens você pode experimentar o `clip-path`:

### Usando clip-path: circle

```css
.arredondar {
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
            clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<img class="arredondar" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShnZP.png?s=328&g=1">
```

### Usando clip-path com borda (simulada)

```css
.arredondar {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f00;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 0; /*remove "white spaces"*/
}

.arredondar, .arredondar img {
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
            clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="arredondar"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShnZP.png?s=328&g=1"></div>
```

---

### Suporte

Conforme o [**CanIUse**](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) o suporte ainda é um pouco limitado, navegadores com suporte:

- Firefox 52 (suporte parcial)
- Firefox 55+
- Chrome 49 (suporte parcial com prefixo)
- Chrome 60 (suporte parcial - Opera usa a mesma tecnologia do Chrome)
- Safari (suporte parcial com prefixo)

> É importante notar que pela MDN ainda é considerado uma **tecnologia experimental**

Answer (score 2):

Vou dar uma resposta que pode ser considera um pouco deselegante, mas como não foram colocadas regras a não ser que seja com CSS e sem `border-radius` ai vai mais uma sugestão *(mesmo que "polêmica")...*

Primeiro vc vai precisar de uma fonte bem geométrica tipo a [Futura](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/futura), que tem a letra **O** como um circulo perfeito. Outro detalhe, quanto mais "grosso" o traço da fonte mais fácil de fazer o efeito, então quanto mais **Bold** melhor

No meu exemplo eu usei uma fonte nesses requisitos que achei no Google Fonts a [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat)

Depois disso eu apenas criei alguns estilos de css para elementos **::after** que usei para cobrir os "olhos" dos caracteres. Resumindo basta usar *pseudo elementos* para tampar os buracos da fonte e ter o *circulo perfeito* e outras formas...

Veja o resultado no exemplo:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: azure;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.texto {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    font-size: 10rem;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.texto-o::after, .texto-p::after, .texto-a::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
}
.texto-o::after {
    top: 30%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 45%;
}
.texto-p::after {
    top: 30%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.75);
}
.texto-a::after {
    top: 30%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 35%;
    background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/40/40);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,900" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    <span class="texto texto-o">o</span>
    <span class="texto texto-p">p</span>
    <span class="texto texto-a">a</span>
    <span class="texto">!</span>
</div>
```

**OBS:** funciona do IE8 pra cima https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Answer (score -3):

```
<img class=”element” src=”image.png” />
<p>Lorem ipsum…</p>

<style>
.element{
  shape-outside: url(image.png);
  shape-image-threshold: 0.5;
  float: left;
}
</style>
```

Fonte:http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/?redirect_from_locale=pt

Comment: Retirei o voto. Não funcionou

Comment: Trágico...           Trágico...

Comment: Só pra constar Paulo, não fui eu quem negativou, na verdade eu nunca tinha notado esta pergunta e respostas, no entanto preciso comentar, o `shape-outside` não funciona da maneira que você presumiu, no caso só vai funcionar se a imagem já for arredondada, logo o efeito dele é no "texto" e não vai criar bordas arredondadas. Quero ressaltar que é uma tecnologia considerada experimental ainda e que somente o Chrome suporta (Firefox e Edge não suportam e Safari só com prefixo).