# Como desenhar 3 círculos em CSS com 1 div

Tags: html, css, css3

Gostaria de fazer 3 icones em CSS, porém não quero fazer com vários div, com div filhos, etc.

Gostaria algo clean, como

```
<div class="Status1"></div>
<div class="Status2"></div>
<div class="Status3"></div>
```

Consegui fazendo com vários div (um para borda) e um div para cada círculo, no caso ficou até com 4 divs, para fazer o Status=3.

**No JsFiddler como eu fiz**
https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/rchdwy1f/11/

**Meu código:**

```
<div class="quadrado">
  <div class="bolaCinza"> </div>
  <div class="bolaAzul"> </div>
  <div class="bolaRed"> </div>
</div>
```

Resultado final:
Status=1
[image: Status1]
Status=2
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Status=3
[image: Status3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode ser que existam outras formas de fazer, mas a mais simples que eu achei foi usando uma sequência de 3 `radial-gradient`.

Repare que eu tenho apenas uma `div`, porém a `div` que tem 1 bola tem 1 `radial-gradiente` no `background-image`, a que tem 2 bolas tem 2 `radial`, e a que tem 3 bolas vai ter 3 `radial-gradiente` dentro do `background-image`.

É simples de configura dentro do próprio gradiente vc contra o `X/Y` para posicionar as bolinhas e as cores... Link com a documentação da Mozilla sobre `radial-gradiente`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}

[class^="bola"] {
    width: 44px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.bolaCinza {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 12px 10px, #fff 0px, #fff 5px, #000 6px);
}
.bolaAzul {
    background-image:   radial-gradient(circle at 12px 10px, #fff 0px, #fff 5px, transparent 6px),
                        radial-gradient(circle at 22px 10px, #00f 0px, #00f 5px, #000 6px);
}
.bolaRed {
    background-image:   radial-gradient(circle at 12px 10px, #fff 0px, #fff 5px, transparent 6px),
                        radial-gradient(circle at 22px 10px, #00f 0px, #00f 5px, transparent 6px),
                        radial-gradient(circle at 32px 10px, #f00 0px, #f00 5px, #000 6px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bolaCinza"></div>
<div class="bolaAzul"></div>
<div class="bolaRed"></div>
```

Comment: Basicamente essa técnica: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101323/

Comment: @Bacco essa pergunta é um clássico ;)

Comment: No IE aqui ficou da forma que coloquei na resposta. :(

Comment: @Sam ai renderizou na tela bem feio mesmo... não sei dizer pq... mas no geral gradiente não denderiza bem no browser mesmo, principalmente na diagonal e em círculos, por isso eu deixei 1px de "transição" na cor do gradiente entre uma cor e outra